# k3d tries to pull Docker image instead of using the local one

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, k3d

Just study the core of K8S on local machine (Linux Mint 20.2).

Created one node cluster locally with:

> k3d cluster create mycluster

And now I want to run spring boot application in a container.
I build local image:

> library:0.1.0

And here is snippet from `Deployment.yml`:

```
spec:
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 40
  containers:
    - name: 'library'
      image: library:0.1.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Despite the fact that image is already built:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
library       0.1.0     254c13416f46   About an hour ago   462MB
```

Starting the container fails:

```
pod/library-867dfb64db-vndtj    Pulling image "library:0.1.0"
pod/library-867dfb64db-vndtj    Failed to pull image "library:0.1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "library:0.1.0": failed to resolve reference "library:0.1.0": failed to do request: Head "https://...com/v2/library/manifests/0.1.0": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
pod/library-867dfb64db-vndtj    Error: ErrImagePull
pod/library-867dfb64db-vndtj    Error: ImagePullBackOff
pod/library-867dfb64db-vndtj    Back-off pulling image "library:0.1.0"
```

***How to resolve local images visibility for k3d cluster?***

---

Solution:

Update the `Deployment.yml`:

```
spec:
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 40
  containers:
    - name: 'library-xp'
      image: xpinjection/library:0.1.0
      imagePullPolicy: Never
```

And import the image to cluster:

> k3d image import xpinjection/library:0.1.0 -c mycluster

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use a docker registry, you have to import the locally built image into the k3d cluster:

```
k3d image import [IMAGE | ARCHIVE [IMAGE | ARCHIVE...]] [flags]
```

But don't forget to configure in your deployment:

```
imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: I will check later

Comment: got the time to check?

Comment: After running k3d image import, is something supposed to happen? How do you actually start a pod from there?

Comment: Actually, I ran `kubectl apply -f pod_manifest.yml` and that started the pod correctly.